# Cordova - Is it possible to list .bap files inside Android tablet directory "internal storage/bap"?

Tags: android, reactjs, cordova, hybrid

I'm totally new to Cordova and my current project happens to be implemented with that. I would need a way to read and list files inside a directory located at `Internal storage/bap`.

I've tried almost every possible way Google has given to me but without luck. If someone has any idea or could point me in the right direction, it would be really appreciated!

### Edit

Managed to at least log the files with the following function, just had to be exact with the path and pass a full native path to the desired directory:

```js
function listDir(path: string): any {
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
    path,
    function(directory) {
      var reader = directory.createReader();
      reader.readEntries(
        function(entries: any) {
          console.log("entries inside listDir");
          console.log(entries);
        },
        function(err: any) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
    },
    function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey! Just to try and help you with finding answers I’d say your question is a bit broad and answering it would entail a tutorial-like explanation which Stack Overflow is not necessarily the best place for. If you have the code for what you’re trying so far, edit your answer and add it so people can help you pointing out the problems in your approach and then move in the right direction.

Comment: @Oxfist yea just edited the question with a solution I managed to find out.